# Automatiaclly crop website before printing the page

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have a HTML file that triggers print() when you click a button. How do you crop the page so the site name and url does not show up?

Comment: Whoever thumbed this down, realize that it's OK to have duplicate questions. Simply mark them as duplicate and link the original post. There may be more than one way of asking the same question; some people who think of this as a cropping operation would never arrive at the original Q/A if they had not found this post.

Answer (score 0):

You cant, including URL and/or title is up to the browsers print dialog.